# Bootstrap Carousel not centering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have downloaded bootstrap and have the following code in the head section

```
<link ref="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
<script src="js/respond.js"></script>
```

However I want my whole slider to be 100% in width and the images to be 80% wide however my images although I have used `margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;` doesn't want to centre it creeps over to the right.

My code is

```
<div id="the-slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#the-slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#the-slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#the-slider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#the-slider" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        <li data-target="#the-slider" data-slide-to="4"></li>
        <li data-target="#the-slider" data-slide-to="5"></li>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner">      
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="file:///Users/Luke/Documents/Aviramp/Images/Slideshow-2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="..." id="img">
        </div> <!--item 1-->
        <div class="item">
           <img src="file:///Users/Luke/Documents/Aviramp/Images/Slideshow-1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="..." id="img">
        </div> <!--item 2-->
        <div class="item">
           <img src="file:///Users/Luke/Documents/Aviramp/Images/Slideshow.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="..." id="img">
        </div> <!--item 2-->
        <div class="item">
           <img src="file:///Users/Luke/Documents/Aviramp/Images/Slideshow-3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="..." id="img">
        </div> <!--item 2-->
        <div class="item">
           <img src="file:///Users/Luke/Documents/Aviramp/Images/Slideshow-4.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="..." id="img">
        </div> <!--item 2-->
        <div class="item">
           <img src="file:///Users/Luke/Documents/Aviramp/Images/Slideshow-5.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="..." id="img">
        </div> <!--item 2-->
    </div> <!--carousel-inner-->

    <!--controls-->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#the-slider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#the-slider" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>

</div><!--the-slider-->

<!--container-->
<!-- javascript -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
#img {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
}
#the-slider {
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

As you will see it creeps to the right, look at photo attached to see what I mean.[image: PHOTO] Its only slight but I NEED it central!

Comment: please show your code in jsfiddle

Comment: Try display:block and margin:0 auto instead of margin-left/right: auto;

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the class **.img-responsive**, you need to use **margin:0px auto** to center.

Hint, set the width you want,  to a parent div, and center the image with **margin: 0px auto;**

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to simulate your problem on JSFiddle. The aligning should be fine with just:

```
 img {
    margin: auto auto; 
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e1mw6myL/

I just got some random pictures in it. The first picture is smaller than other..
 It could be that your image is too big (there is a max-width: 100% on **.img-responsive**)

Try using other images and look if those images give you the same problem.